# Android display fields from list of instances

Tags: java, android

I have a list of instances from on class. Every instance got 4 fields. Now I want to display this fields. What is the correct way to do it?

Here is my folder hierarchie

[image: image_1]

`MainActivity`

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public userManager userManager = new userManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void createUser(View view){
        EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iPassword);
        EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iAge);
        EditText sex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iSex);


        this.userManager.createUser(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(sex.getText().toString()));
    }

    public void showAllUser(View view){

    }
}
```

`userManager`

```html
public class userManager {
    public List<user> userList = new ArrayList<user>();

    public boolean createUser(String username, String password, int age, int sex){
        if(username != null && !username.isEmpty() || password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
            this.userList.add(new user(username, password, age, sex));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void displayAllUser(){

    }
}
```

`user`

```html
public class user {
    //region properties
    //region username
    private String username;

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }
    //endregion

    //region password
    private String password;

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
    //endregion

    //region age
    private int age;

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    //endregion age

    //0 don't know, 1 male, 2 female
    //region sex
    int sex;

    public void setSex(int sex){
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public int getSex(){
        return this.sex;
    }
    //endregion sex
    //endregion properties

    //region c'tor
    public user(){

    }

    public user(String username, String password, int age, int sex){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    //endregion
}
```

And here is the `activity_main.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="overbit.user.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_username"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/iUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_password"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/iPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_age"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/iAge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_sex"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/iSex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_add_user"
            android:onClick="createUser"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_output_user"
            android:onClick="showAllUser"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I could write into the method `displayAllUser` (class = userManager) a `for loop`, to get each instance and his fields. But then? I have to give them back to the `MainActivity`? How can return much data like this back to the `MainActity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Building Layouts with an Adapter

Check this out this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

and this: 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

You need a view of the type AdapterView
You can populate an AdapterView such as ListView or GridView by binding the AdapterView instance to an Adapter, which retrieves data from an external source and creates a View that represents each data entry.

Android also provides several subclasses of Adapter that are useful for retrieving different kinds of data and building views for an AdapterView.

Check the above links to understand how to go about implementing the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Thats exactly what I searched for.